# Time series: predicting covariates for missing years from historical values

Tags: time-series, econometrics, missing-data

I'm working with a time-series dataset where my dependent variable is measured annually from 2018-2021 but my covariates are not all measured over the same period. For instance, $x_1$ is measured from 2010-2016, $x_2$ from 2010-2019, etc.

I'd like to predict the value of $x_1$ for 2017-2021 and for $x_2$ for 2020 and 2021 while still propagating uncertainty in the predictions. What I've read about imputation seems geared to situations where there is missing data for some but not all observations and there isn't historical data. How is this issue typically addressed? Thanks!

Comment: Practically, many analysts just use LOCF in these settings. The point is that it is not meant to be an imputation of the concurrent value of $x$, but is quite literally the last known value of $x$. Consider how much more practical that is in most prediction and inferential settings.

Comment: That's definitely a more straightforward solution, but I was hoping to account for trends in the data. For example, some covariates I'm examining are town budgets, which have tended to increase due to inflation.

Comment: You have to be more specific than that. LOCF definitely "accounts for trends in the data". If $x_1$ really hasn't been measured for 2 years prior to the observation period for the response, you have a hard case to make whatever modeling strategy you use. Sometimes you have to take a 10,000 ft view at your data and say the desired analysis just isn't possible. In some cases, perhaps even this one, modeling can recover efficiency, but can't make an entirely impossible analysis possible.

Comment: However, I've seen time-series analyses with non-concurrent and non-central exposure modeling. A modeling technique called universal kriging combines spectral analysis with variogram models to predict and quantify the variability of autoregressive effects in a sparse timeseries. This can be combined with multivariate regression in a method called Land Use Regression. It's insanely complicated to put it politely.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tips @AdamO. I was thinking of just using a linear model, e.g., $x_{t,i} = \beta_i + \beta_{t,i}t +\epsilon_{i,t}$ (for observation i and historical years t) and estimating the distribution of the coefficients, then using it to make predictions about the missing years, with the variance in the parameters beta_i and beta_{t,i} reflecting uncertainty in the “true” parameter values.